# extjs handle http responses globally

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm a little bit stuck with ajax/http exception handling: I'm trying to handle `401` exception globally in extjs, and trying to use the following code to do this:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (conn, response, options) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
        log.console = '401 recieved';
    }
});
```

It works ok and handles `401`, BUT only when you explicitly make `Ext.Ajax.request()`. It doesn't handle ajax stores... So here comes the question: can I handle ALL `401 http` errors came to my application? Thanks!

Comment: what version of Extjs are you using?  I have done this in my app, but the code is different for Extjs 4 and 3

Comment: @Reimius, for now I'm using Ext JS ver. 4.1. Do you think such a basic thing could be rewritten/reworked?

Comment: We override one of the methods in Ext.data.Connection for our application, everything that uses ajax inherits from that class.  I'll provide an example if I get time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do your error handling for any Ext classes you use that do Ajax connections.  Some of these may include `Ext.data.Connection`, `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax`, and `Ext.form.action.Action`.

For example, with `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax`, you can override the class to add a listener on `requestexception`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.override.AjaxProxy', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent(config);
        this.on('requestexception', MyApp.utils.Utils.handle401Error);
    }
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I considered such a solution... just thought there something like we have for plain AJAX. Thanks for your response though, it's really helpful!